# how to select data with ado.net from mssql

Tags: c#, mysql, json, select, ado.net

My mission is to get result from database which should look like this:

```
[
  {
    LicenseNumber = "xxx", //string, that can contain numbers
    EMailAddress = "people@gmail.com",
    PhoneNumber = "+370 600 00001",
    OrganisationName = "work place"
  }
]
```

I got the following code:

```
public class DataController : ApiController
        {
            [Authorize]
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("api/participants")]
            public JsonResult<Array> Get(string participantCode)
            {
                JsonResult<Array> result = null;
                string connectionString = "Server=db1.lagoon.lt;Database=LagoonOcean_LT;Integrated Security=True";               
                string queryString =
                    "SELECT p.LicenseNumber, p.EMailAddress, p.PhoneNumber, w.OrganisationName" + 
                    "FROM [LagoonOcean_LT].[dbo].[Person] p.inner join LagoonOcean_LT.dbo.PersonMainWorkplaceVW w on w.PersonUUID = p.PersonUUID" +
                    "WHERE LicenseNumber == participantCode;";
                int paramValue = 5;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))                   
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", paramValue);


                    var participants = new List<object>();
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                participants.Add(new[]{new
                                    {
                                    LicenseNumber = reader[0],
                                    EMailAddress = reader[1],
                                    PhoneNumber = reader[2],
                                    OrganisationName = reader[3]
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                  result = Json<Array>(participants.ToArray());
                 }
                return result;
            }
        }
```

but i get an error:

*An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in DoctorInfoWebService.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '.'.*

I think there is something wrong with selecting data or connection string

Comment: I think you have a typo in your FROM statement `FROM [LagoonOcean_LT].[dbo].[Person] p.inner join`. Notice t '.' after `p`? Try to remove that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FROM [LagoonOcean_LT].[dbo].[Person] p.inner
```

What are you trying to do here ? Remove the `.` after p. Also the default schema is dbo it is not needed to be written.

Comment: Removing dot will not help, he need replace dot with space

Comment: Okay I think it is obvious that he should not write pinner to work. In my opinion this is obvious.

Comment: It is not obvious from your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the query is wrong. If you want to use prefix then you need to declare it as name

```
SELECT p.Name FROM Students p WHERE p.Id = 1
```

Second, if you are using ADO.NET, maybe it is better to try implementation with EntityFramework and LINQ expression, it is much more clear and simple. You can a look from those sources:
[LINQ sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738645(v=vs.110).aspx)
[EntityFramework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)